# Array of ArrayLists Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the following code (part of a larger program - the exception is thrown on the line where "add" is called).

```
public class A
{
    static ArrayList<Integer> sets[];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         sets = new ArrayList[5];
         sets[0].add(1);
    }
}
```

I also do not understand why the compiler is requiring me to make any class level variables static (e.g. the ArrayList).  As far as I can tell, these things shouldn't be in a static context (in terms of coding practice, not compiler problems) and yet the compiler is requiring it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sets = new ArrayList[5];
```

Just fills 5 spots with `null`

You need to explicitly set `ArrayList()` for each position before doing `add()` call.

Example:

```
sets[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sets[0].add(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
sets = new ArrayList[5];
```

allocates the array, but does not place an ArrayList in any element of the array.

You would need

```
sets[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sets[0].add(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array is initialized with `null` values.

```
//it will initialize sets variable
sets = new ArrayList[5];
//but set[0], set[1]... and on are null
```

You should initialize the array items as well before using them

```
sets[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
sets[0].add(1);
```

Also, for a better design, you should program oriented to interfaces instead of the class. See  [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197) for more info.

In short, your code should look like

```
public class A {
    static List<Integer> sets[];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sets = new List[5];
        sets[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sets[0].add(1);
        //extending your code in order to use more than one value of the List array
        sets[1] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sets[1].add(20);
        for(List<Integer> list : sets) {
            if (list != null) {
                System.out.println(list.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```